# Does anyone know how to get query from query inspector in Grafana dashboard using http API via api request?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-api, httpapi

I'm trying to fetch data from query that is located in Grafana dashboard. I have an idea to get results from dashboard but not from the query inspector in Grafana.

I have fetched data from dashboard but not from the query inspector.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what are you trying to accomplish? Also, if you're trying to get data, why don't you request data straight from the data source being used?